# Best way to mirror folders

Tags: windows, sync, mirroring

I want to mirror two folders so a change in one is reflected in others.

am i best off making a home brew solutions with RoboCopy and /MIR or is there a decent preferably free app to do it for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If these folders are on the same computer, then you can create *a single* folder and a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to that folder, known as a [junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) on Windows. This way you don't need to synchronise at all: the two folders are actually one single folder with two names, and hence are in-sync by definition. (Note that Windows does not support junctions to directories on remote shares.)

Or, if these directories are on two (or more) different computers, or maybe even different operating systems, maybe sign up for [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/)? It's free for 2GB (up to 3GB [with referrals](https://www.dropbox.com/help/category/Referrals)). This will synchronise automatically, and also give you all other nice Dropbox [features](http://www.dropbox.com/features) such as backup, revision history, online access and file sharing.

Dropbox recognises if computers are in the same network, for super fast transfer using [LAN Sync](http://www.dropbox.com/help/137), but even that requires an internet connection while (automatically) synchronising. And the folders you want to synchronise should reside within the Dropbox folder (which itself you can locate anywhere you want).

Answer (score 11):

You could take a look at [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=c26efa36-98e0-4ee9-a7c5-98d0592d8c52&displaylang=en) from Microsoft. It's got a number options for copying data between folders - [this page](http://www.pchell.com/support/synctoy.shtml) has a useful guide on it's use and explains what the various options do:

> Now, you need to choose how you want to backup the information. You can perform the following tasks between two folders:
>
> - **Synchronize**: New and updated files are copied both ways. Renames and deletes in one folder is repeated on the other.
> - **Echo**: New and updated files are copied left to right. Renames and deletes on the left are repeated on the right.
> - **Subscribe**: Updated files on the right are copied to the left is the file name already exists on the left.
> - **Contribute**: New and updated files are copied left to right. Renames on the left are repeated on the right. Similar to Echo, except there are no deletions.
> - **Combine**: New and updated files are copied both ways. Renamed and deleted files are ignored.

Comment: Sounds good, will evaulate it now and accept if its good

Comment: +1 for SyncToy. I'm using it in both the Echo and Contribute modes (for different sets of folders) and it works well for me.

Comment: The bad thing about SyncToy is that it is not real-time, you have to open the app and "Run" the script each time you want to sync.

Answer (score 4):

if you're using **[Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/)**, it's got all you would expect from a modern file manager, including folder synchronization and comparison.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two great free products:

[SyncBack Freeware](http://www.2brightsparks.com/downloads.html) (rather toward the end of the page)
[Allway Sync](http://allwaysync.com/) (EDIT: No longer free.)

Comment: "Customer agrees that Allway Sync Free has certain limitations and that these limitations may change over time without notice or obligation on the part of Developer. Currently, the limitations may not allow Customer to process more than 40,000 files in any consecutive 30-days." -- Allway Sync License: https://allwaysync.com/license